# Erro ao instalar npm install @react-navigation/stack -> expo start disconnected

Tags: javascript, react, react-native, npm, expo

sou novo no React native e estou tentando instalar o react navigation stack através do comando npm install @react-navigation/stack para utilizar em um projeto de um app com o react native, no entanto após executar esse comando para instalar essa biblioteca, dá erro como se o expo cli fosse desinstalado por esse comando, algum arquivo excluido não sei ;(

Preciso instalar essa biblioteca para criar o aplicativo. Como proceder nesse caso?

Veja o que ocorre no cmd ao executar o comando npm install @react-navigation/stack

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que rodo esse comando, o expo dá erro :(

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso muito da ajuda de vocês! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver dessa forma, rodando os comandos:

Npm upgrade
Npm i
Npm i (nome-do-pacote) -> no meu exemplo é o npm install @react-navigation/stack

Answer (score 0):

Ao inciar o servidor do expo através do yarn start da esse erro no cmd

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tá falando que o RN não esta instalado, tente instalar de novo. Se você instalou e ainda ficar esse erro, tenta criar o arquivo em outra pasta